# How can I implement login and logout in Android using Servlet and HttpSession?

Tags: java, android, servlets, servlet-3.0, httpsession

I understand how to created the HttpSession and invalidate it in Servlet to perform login/logout. But my problem is Android, I don't know how to get the Session or Perform the logout. Is cookies same as the Session. Can anyone direct me to the right Direction?

Comment: Don't downvote it if you don't know, or don't understand the question

Comment: There is not session in Android. There are some other solutions for keeping login status on Mobile App: 1. Store username/password (not suggest) 2. Make a access_token for client which can be added to the header of HTTP request to get all resource from the server.(You can read the material of Oauth2.0)

Comment: Thanks will definitely look into it